# Less repetitive way to add class to DOM element with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building an AngularJS application using materializecss for the UI.

Now, in the examples of materializecss, they add the `focused` class to all its forms elements in order to get certain behavior.

In order to achieve this, the immediate solution is to add the `ng-class` to the parent container asking for a variable which will be setting by using the `ng-blur` and `ng-focus` attributes in the input element.

This code ilustrates the above solution:

```
<div id="myFieldParent" data-ng-class="{'focused': vm.focused}">
    <input type="text" name="myfield" data-ng-model="vm.myfield"
        data-ng-focus="vm.focused = true" data-ng-blur="vm.focused = false"/>
</div>
```

Is there any way to make this process less repetitive for all the components of my forms?

Comment: Are the form elements similar enough that you could replace them with a directive that includes those attributes?

Comment: Yes, they are. I think I found the solution. Let me share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a directive:

```
(function () {
     'use strict';

    function focused() {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link:
            function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var clazz = attrs['focused'] || "focused";

                var parent = angular.element(element.parent());
                element.on("focus",function () {
                    if (!parent.hasClass(clazz)) {
                        parent.addClass(clazz)
                    }
                    scope.$apply();
                });
                element.on("blur",function () {
                    if (parent.hasClass(clazz)) {
                        parent.removeClass(clazz)
                    }
                    scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        }
    }

    angular.module('app')
        .directive('focused', [focused]);
 }());
```

Now, I can reduce my code to this:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="myfield" data-ng-model="vm.myfield"
        data-ng-focused/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try to make a component / directive which encapsulates this behavior, similar to this: [AngularJS custom text input component](https://embed.plnkr.co/Du4KqQ/). And then you use directive / component like this:

```
<my-input model="vm.myField" name="myField"></my-input>
```

You have simplicity of `ng-class` solution, but code is still DRY.